# Activating and deactivating comments not working properly in panel admin

Tags: python, django

After activate a comment by checking the active box to showing that comment to the user on template, everything seems good but after deactivating that comment again, it makes a new instance or in another word copying that comment in panel admin as an active, it's like duplicating the comments after unchecking the active box.
I am using Postgresql database, Is that possible this issue came from database?

models.py

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

forms.py

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

views.py

```py
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                             status='published',
                             publish__year=year,
                             publish__month=month,
                             publish__day=day)
    # List of active comments for this post
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # A comment was posted
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.post = post
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post, 'comments': comments,
                                                     'new_comment': new_comment,
                                                     'comment_form': comment_form})
```

admin.py

```py
@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'post', 'created', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created', 'updated')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z30AO.png) this comment duplicated.

UPDATE:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
<p class="date">
    Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
</p>
{{ post.body|linebreaks }}
<p>
    <a href="{% url "blog:post_share" post.id %}">
        Share this post
    </a>
</p>
{% with comments.count as total_comments %}
    {% if total_comments %}
        <h2>
            {{ total_comments }} comment{{ total_comments|pluralize }}
        </h2>
    {% else %}
        <h2>0 Comment</h2>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="comment">
        <p class="info">
            Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by {{ comment.name }}
            {{ comment.created }}
        </p>
        {{ comment.body|linebreaks }}
    </div>
{% empty %}
    <p>There are no comments yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
{% if new_comment %}
    <h2>Your comment has been added.</h2>
{% else %}
    <h2>Add a new comment</h2>
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ comment_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add comment"></p>
    </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to pass `instance=post` to both places where you are initialising your `CommentForm`. This is required when editing existing objects

Comment: After passing `instance=post` to both `CommentForm` panel admin doesn't show any comments, and comments body auto filling with post body in template. by the way I don't want to edit my comments i want to activate and deactivate comments from panel admin so i don't know why `instance=post` is matter.

Comment: Can you share the form template? You need to pass the id of the comment being edited if you would like to edit an existing comment

Comment: Template added as an update, you mean even if i want to enable and disable comments from panel admin i need to do this, i don't want to edit comments, just showing or stop showing them on template is my point.